# How [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]; works?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

How the following works?

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

From where i can set the value for this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not really an iPhone question... you may want to re-word this as something like "Is there a standard way to set the app version for Android apps?" and only tag it for android.

Comment: I disagree. Android has no info dictionary and no bundle, it's totally different. That line of code returns you your app version string in iOS. If you need this, you should specifically ask how to get this in android. Given your question's title, it will be seen mostly by iOS developer who probably don't really know or don't have as much experience. If you simply ask the android group how to get and where to set this information /specifically/ for Android, I think you'll get a lot more responses.

Comment: ok, question is edited, now. Thanks. :)

Comment: This question is way too vague. Asking "How does this work?" requires a very complex answer. What *exactly* do you want to know?

Comment: How can i set build version in info.plist programatically?

Comment: Not very related with the question, but prefere use kCFBundleVersionKey instead of your literal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for this is derived from your application's root `Info.plist` file. Newer versions of Xcode pretty-print this key as "Bundle version".

Comment: Is it like every time, i want to change, i have to edit **info.plist** manually??

Comment: How often do you want to change it? You cannot modify it while it is on the device as it would break the code-signing for your app. You can update it by means of a script every time you commit a change to `git`, etc. though.

Comment: whenever i edit in the code, i need to increment it.
So, i need to change it manually?